# Left join if one table has a column with cells containing multiple values?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, left-join

I have two tables that I want to merge together, an example row from table 1 looks like this:

| Gene.Name | Classified_Hotspot_Cancer |
| --- | --- |
| NRAS | Extrahepatic Cholangiocarcinoma, Intrahepatic Cholangiocarcinoma, Perihilar Cholangiocarcinoma, Cholangiocarcinoma |

Instead of commas however, these cancer types are divided by the "|" symbol.

In table 2, I have specific combinations of cancers and genes.

| Gene.Name | Full_Name |
| --- | --- |
| NRAS | Intrahepatic Cholangiocarcinoma |
| NRAS | Cholangiocarcinoma |

I want to left_join table 2 to table 1, so that if Gene.Name is equal in both tables, and Full_Name equals any of the values in the Classified_Hotspot_Cancers, I get a product like this:

| Gene.Name | Classified_Hotspot_Cancer | Cancer_with_Gene |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NRAS | Extrahepatic Cholangiocarcinoma, Intrahepatic Cholangiocarcinoma, Perihilar Cholangiocarcinoma, Cholangiocarcinoma | Intrahepatic Cholangiocarcinoma, Cholangiocarcinoma |

I realize this is probably a two-step process of left_joining table 2 to table 1, and then collapsing the Cancer_with_Gene into one row? As always, any help is deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We can do a group by `paste` and then do a join

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Gene.Name) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(Full_Name = str_c(Full_Name, collapse= ", "), 
          .groups = 'drop') %>%
    right_join(df1)
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, thanks for the answer, when I seem to run however I simply get a column called ".groups" with only NA values?

Comment: @KLM117 Can you show `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: I used `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.7’` I am assuming that your package dplyr to be an older version, thus probably `.groups` were not introduced at that time

Comment: Hi Akrun, it's `'1.0.6'`

Comment: @KLM117 what do you get when you do `summarise(Full_Name = str_c(Full_Name, collapse= ", "))`

Comment: @KLM117 ok, then probably you have `plyr` loaded which masked dplyr summarise.e. `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% plyr::summarise(out = length(Sepal.Length), .groups = 'drop')`

Comment: @KLM117 try the update i.e. `dplyr::summarise` should work

Comment: Hi Akrun, so when I ran  `summarise(Full_Name = str_c(Full_Name, collapse= ", "))` I got a 1 x 1 dataframe with the Full_Names. I do have plyr loaded so I'll give what you suggested a go!

Comment: @KLM117 if it is plyr::summarise, the behavior is different

Comment: So I'm not using the `plyr::summarise` but are you saying that if the package is loaded it will change how what you've suggested has run?

Comment: @KLM117 what I meant is that if you load `plyr` package after `dplyr`, some common functions i.e. summarise, mutate etc are masked by the newly loaded plyr.  You don't have to use `plyr::summarise` as this automatically does.  In order to reverse this behavior, you have to specify `dplyr::summarise`

Comment: Probably there is a message when you load `library(plyr)` i.e. summarise is masked or so..

Comment: @KLM117 another option is to do this on a fresh `R` session with only `library(dplyr);library(stringr)` loaded

Comment: Thanks Akrun, I'll try that as well!